# Geometric interpretation for $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f'(x) f(x) dx = 0$, where $f$ has compact support.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuously differentiable with compact support. Then it holds that
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f'(x) f(x)\, \mathrm{d}x = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{-n}^n f'(x)f(x)\,  \mathrm{d}x = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{2} \left( f(n)^2 - f(-n)^2 \right) = 0.$$
Alternatively, this follows immediately from integration by parts. I have two questions:

1. Is there a (geometric) interpretation of the above integral and the fact it vanishes? In the simple case, where you take a symmetric bump function with support, say, $[-1,1]$, the integrals over $[-1,0]$ and $[0,1]$ cancel out but in general things don't seem to be this easy.
2. Can something be said about integrals of the form $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (f'(x))^k f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x,$$ with $f$ as above and $k \in \mathbb{N}$? For even $k$, it doesn't always vanish (as the bump function example shows), what about odd $k$? Is there some "generic" method to evaluate integrals of this form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\phi$ is a $C^1$ function with compact support, then $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\phi'(x)\,dx=0$. Think of the graph of $\phi$ as the profile of a hill. You start on the left extreme of the support at level $0$ and finish at the right one at the same level. What you climb up is exactly the same as what you climb down.

In the first example we can take $\phi(x)=(f(x))^2/2$. In general, $(f'(x))^kf(x)$ is the derivative of a compactly supported function only if $k=1$.

Comment: Thank you! However, I think that with the same reasoning, one should give conditions for the integral of $(f'(x))^{2k+1} f(x)$ to vanish, as the weight given by the power $2k+1$ should be the same for the distance climbed up than for the one climbed down.

Comment: The integral vanishes for odd powers if for instance $f$ is symmetric around the midpoint of its support, since then $f'$ will be odd with respect to that point. As an example, let $p,q>1$ and $f(x)=x^p(1-x)^q$ on $[0,1]$, $0$ everywhere else. $\phi$ is $C^1$ with compact support. $\int_0^1(f'(x))^{2k+1}f(x)\,dx=0$ for $k\ge1$ if and only if $p=q$.